# I want to delete records from different tables in prisma client

Tags: sql, prisma

I want to delete a record from the User table and another one from the Post table using the userId. I'm aware that using two separate queries allows me to achieve this, but I'm interested in utilizing a single query to delete both records simultaneously. Is this feasible?

I have models here for Prisma ORM:

```
model User {
    userId    Int     @default(@autoincrement())
    name      String
    Post      Post?
}

model Post {
    userId    Int     @id @map("user_id")
    user      User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [userId])
    content   String
}
```

Using two separate queries to delete two related tables:

```
await prisma.$transaction([
  prisma.user.delete({
    where: {
      userId: 1,
    },
  }),
  prisma.post.delete({
    where: {
      userId: 1,
    },
  }),
]);
```